# Calculating a user's average compared to all averages

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document with data like so:

```
{  
   "user":"john",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "score":100
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "user":"ben",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "score":110
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "user":"john",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":2,
         "score":110
      }
   ]
},
{  
   "user":"steve",
   "games":[  
      {  
         "id":2,
         "score":120
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to be able to calculate "johns" score average for all games he's played in comparison to everyone else.

For example,

John played in both game 1 and 2, so we would calculate every user's average score for games given id 1, and id 2.

ID 1 should provide `(100 + 110 / 2) = 107.5` and ID 2 should give `(120 + 110 / 2) = 115`

I want to be given the difference between John's average score for all the games he's played in for that given ID (he can also have more than one score) and get the difference.

For example, he has one entry in ID 1, so his average score was `100`. The difference between his score and the total ID 1 average of all players is `-7.5`, for ID 2 his average score was `110`, and his difference was -5 as well, so his total difference would be `(-7.5 + -5 / 2) = -6.25` .

I've attempted to this like so:

```
db.entries.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
        "users": "john",
    }},
    {
        "$unwind": '$games'
    },
    {
        "$group": {
        "_id": "$games.id",
        "score": {"$first": "$games.score"}
        },
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$score"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
        "_id": 1,
        "score": {"$avg": "$score"}}
    }
])
```

This gives me John's scores in all games grouped by unique game IDs, however, I'm unsure of how to accomplish the second part where I compare his score to all the other users.

Comment: Sorry, I did that wrong - I will correct this.

Comment: You could shorten your user & game $avg aggregation using a compound group key: `db.games.aggregate([ { $unwind: '$games' }, { $group: { _id: {game: '$games.id', user: '$user'}, score: {$avg: '$games.score'} } } ]);`.

Comment: @metame I have keys existing on the individual fields, do compound ones work differently where I would want to have that as well?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking @Wilson.  The compound key just allows you to group items more specifically, instead of having to do a $group stage for both games.id & user, you can group all docs with a unique game id and unique user in one step.

Answer (score 1):

Get everyone' avg of each game:

```
db.scores.aggregate(
  {
     $unwind : "$games"
  },
  {
    $group: {
       "_id" : "$games.id",
       "gameAvg" : {$avg : "$games.score"},
    }
  }
)
```

Output like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(2), 
    "gameAvg" : 115.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "gameAvg" : 105.0
}
```

Get John' avg for each game:

```
db.scores.aggregate(
  {
     $unwind : "$games"
  },
  {
     $match : {
        "user" : "john", 
     }
  },
  {
    $group: {
       "_id" : "$games.id",
       "gameAvg" : {$avg : "$games.score"},
    }
  }
)
```

Output like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(2), 
    "gameAvg" : 110.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "gameAvg" : 100.0
}
```

1. So you can run logic for calculating difference of each game by 2 loops
2. Get AVG of all differences i.e Answer you want

Answer (score 0):

To do both in the same aggregation pipeline, you can do a $push of the user docs and then an $unwind to get the user averages.

```
db.games.aggregate([ 
    { 
        $unwind: '$games' 
    }, 
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: '$games.id', 
            score: {$avg: '$games.score'}, 
            user_scores: { 
                $push : { user: '$user', score: '$games.score' } 
            } 
        } 
     }, 
     { 
         $unwind: '$user_scores' 
     }, 
     {
         $group: { 
             _id: { user: '$user_scores.user', game: '$_id' },
             user_avg: { $avg: '$user_scores.score' }, 
             group_avg: { $first: '$score' }
         }
     }, 
     {
         $project: { 
             _id: 0, 
             user: '$_id.user', 
             game: '$_id.game', 
             avg_diff: { $subtract: ['$group_avg', '$user_avg'] } 
         }
     }
]);
```

Comment: Would this do all players in the document? Would this still work using a `match` to find just a specific users but still have him compared to everyone else?

Comment: This gives all users. If you want a specific user, do a $match at the end.

Comment: Think of this as a good template to play around with. Aggregation is not particularly quick, each step adds time. How much will be determined by db size and what you're doing. Figuring out how to get the answer for all games would be a good thing for you to research and discover yourself. :)